# Select text except empty white space using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of trouble with text selection on my website. I want to be able to select the text-only & not the excess white space between paragraphs on any sides of the text.

At the moment, I can, with using the `::selection` & having it's own background colour. However I believe my code is all screwy & I just can't find out how to do it.

This website below is exactly what I want it to do, when selecting the text, the white space between paragraphs is never selected.

[Demo site - Formula one](http://www.formula1.com/content/fom-website/en/championship/drivers/nico-rosberg/Biography.html)

Any & all help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: *However I believe my code is all screwy* Can you post that code?

Comment: I can select and copy/paste ` of 1982 ` in demo link (note the 2 whitespaces at start and end of string), with Win7 Firefox and despite an user config I changed [layout.word_select.eat_space_to_next_word](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Layout.word_select.eat_space_to_next_word)

Comment: In the link you provided, the text selection is as normal as it gets... white space included in the selection... can you provide code / screenshot of what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you guys. Below is a screenshot of what I want. Obviously, the blue background is selecting/highlighting the text-only. I want that. I don't want to be able to select text + background (white space).

[link](http://dc-world.us/what_i_want_select.jpg)

Comment: Your first description was confusing. You don't want the selection to include the white space BETWEEN PARAGRAPHS, and not ALL white space (between words...). Check my answer below :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you just use `<p>` element to wrap each paragraph (that's what the `<p>` element exists for, that's its destiny. Do you want to deny it from doing what its meant for???), the browser will do the magic himself :-)

Check out the [simplest JsFiddle i've ever created](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/boyfh0bz/) :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in how they achieved the effect in the formula website, here are all relevant parts - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k56qqc3r/1/). (I altered fiddle by @Ronen Cypis).

As you can see, thay use an hidden overlay layer

```
.fom-modal-shim {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:1000;

  -moz-opacity:0;
  -khtml-opacity:0;
  -webkit-opacity:0;
  opacity:0;
  -ms-filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  visibility:hidden
}
```

The final effect is achieved by setting `position` of the page container to `relative`.

```
.site-wrapper {
  position:relative
}
```